# add_image_size is not generatin images of correct dimensions

Tags: plugins, media, media-library

I am trying my hands with WP `add_image_size` method and this is the entry in my theme's `function.php`

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
 set_post_thumbnail_size( 100, 65); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions   
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
 add_image_size( 'home_page_featured', 200, 225, true);
}
```

I tried with both parameters of crop factor but seems nothing is working for me.
I am uploading  `Dimensions 628x355` and want that beside all OOB image size, `home_page_featured` should be get created with dimensions 200x225, but WP is generating it as `200x113`

i tried with `Regenerate Thumbnails` plugin but seems like it is not working, not sure where i am doing wrong.

Comment: `add_image_size('home_page_featured',200,225,true);` works ok for me, WP 3.5 and TwentyTwelve: uploading a 628x355 image generates a 200x225 thumbnail. Check if [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) outputs information and do a [full troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list).

Comment: @brasofilo: this is some weired behaviour for me, will check log info

Answer (score 1):

The code bellow should work properly.  Also read this post [WordPress Featured Images – add_image_size() resizing and cropping demo](http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/web-development/wordpress-featured-images-add_image_size-resizing-and-cropping-demo/).

Add this code in the file `functions.php`:
`add_image_size( 'Home Page Featured'', 200, 225, true );`

And call it like this in home page `the_post_thumbnail('Home Page Featured');`

Comment: but you have to reupload images otherwise try {

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/ - This plugin allows you to re-build the post thumbnails. Useful if you use add_image_size() after already having uploaded post thumbnails. (This plugin is slow, but never has out of memory errors).
}